# R terra: [crop] SpatRaster has no values

Tags: raster, r, extents, sf, terra

I am attempting to use `terra::crop()` to crop 30 meter NLCD raster data to a bounding box. The final error that R returns is:

```
Error: [crop] SpatRaster has no values
```

despite the raster data containing values and appearing on any figures I create.

For a reproducible example, I've created three points which plot on a map:

```r
library(terra)
#> Warning: package 'terra' was built under R version 4.0.5
#> terra 1.5.21
library(sf)
#> Warning: package 'sf' was built under R version 4.0.5
#> Linking to GEOS 3.9.1, GDAL 3.4.0, PROJ 8.1.1; sf_use_s2() is TRUE
library(FedData)
library(tmap)
#> Warning: package 'tmap' was built under R version 4.0.5
tdir=tempdir()
points=st_as_sf(x=data.frame(lat=c(42.2,42.4,42.5),
                      lon=c(-76.5,-77.2,-76.8)),
         coords=c('lon','lat')) %>%
  st_set_crs(.,value=4326)

tm_shape(points)+
  tm_dots(col='red',size=1)+
  tm_graticules(lines=F)
```

[image]

With these points, I create a `SpatVector` object from their bounding box:

```
BB = st_as_sfc(st_bbox(points))
BB_for_tmap=BB # Created because tmap doesn't accept SpatVector
BB = terra::vect(BB)
```

Which I then use to pull in the NLCD data and transform it to give it a matching crs to the bounding box of the points:

```
NLCD=get_nlcd(template=as(BB,"Spatial"),
         label='example',
         year=2019,
         extraction.dir = tdir,
         force.redo = T)

NLCD=terra::rast(NLCD)
terra::project(NLCD,BB)
```

We can see that the BB object and the NLCD raster have proper extents and the same CRS. We can also see that the NLCD object contains data:

```
tm_shape(NLCD)+
   tm_raster()+
tm_shape(BB_for_tmap)+
   tm_polygons(col='red',alpha=.5)
#> stars object downsampled to 1191 by 840 cells. See tm_shape manual (argument raster.downsample)
#> Warning: Duplicated levels found. They have been omitted
```

[image]

However, when trying to crop the NLCD data to my `SpatVector` object, I get the following error:

```
test=terra::crop(NLCD,BB,mask=T)
#> Error: [crop] SpatRaster has no values
```

I am wondering where I'm going wrong here.

EDIT: Packages are now up to date and functions have been updated accordingly.

Comment: You should consider updating your packages to the most recent version and probably also update your base R version to 4.2.1. Moreover, `FedData::get_nlcd()` does not seem to have a `landmass` attribute (using v2.5.7).

Comment: @falk-env Thanks. I updated. But the problem persists.

Comment: Still, [FedData::get_nlcd()](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/FedData/versions/2.5.7/topics/get_nlcd) does not have a `landmass` attribute. Unfortunately, your example is not reproducible at the moment.

Comment: @falk-env Right right. Updates provided.

Comment: Should that `get_nlcd` call work now? I get an error and XML returned with "The Specified Key Does Not Exist" which sounds like the AWS url is stale. Oh I have a bad feeling its geofenced to the USA...

Comment: Both have the same CRS? So is `crs(NLCD)=crs(BB)` ok? Otherwise, use `project`

Comment: @Spacedman It works for me. Do you mean those outside the US can't use `get_nlcd()`?

Comment: @aldo_tapia Changed to `terra::project()`

Comment: @geoscience123 yes, even the example in the help for that function fails, and it does say "USA only" in comments (but maybe that is referring to the area its trying to dowload idk). It also fails on an online cloud R environment but I don't know which country that cloud is based in.

Comment: @geoscience123: You could have mentioned you're apparently working with the dev version from GitHub. After receiving `nlcd file ... corrupt or incomplete. Please delete the file and try again.` with the example provided in v2.5.7, I discovered [this](https://github.com/ropensci/FedData/issues/62) issue and installed the development version of `FedData` using `devtools::install_github("ropensci/FedData")`. `get_nlcd` now has a `landmass` attribute using v3.0.0.9000 and I was able to execute your function call.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Basically, the problem are the coordinate reference systems of both layers being inconsistent when using `terra::crop(NLCD, BB, mask = TRUE)`, because you did not save the output from  `terra::project(NLCD, BB)` and continue to work with EPSG: 9001.

```r
NLCD <- get_nlcd(template = as(BB,"Spatial"),
                 label = 'example',
                 year = 2019,
                 force.redo = T)

NLCD <- terra::rast(NLCD)

NLCD
#> class       : SpatRaster 
#> dimensions  : 1478, 2096, 1  (nrow, ncol, nlyr)
#> resolution  : 30, 30  (x, y)
#> extent      : 1525545, 1588425, 2285325, 2329665  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
#> coord. ref. : Albers Conical Equal Area 
#> source      : example_NLCD_Land_Cover_2019.tif 
#> color table : 1 
#> categories  : NLCD Land Cover Class, Histogram, Red, Green, Blue, Opacity 
#> name        : example_NLCD_Land_Cover_2019 
#> min value   :                   Open Water 
#> max value   : Emergent Herbaceous Wetlands

BB
#>  class       : SpatVector 
#>  geometry    : polygons 
#>  dimensions  : 1, 0  (geometries, attributes)
#>  extent      : -77.2, -76.5, 42.2, 42.5  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
#>  coord. ref. : lon/lat WGS 84 (EPSG:4326)
```

You simply need to continue with the raster after reprojection to WGS 84:

```r
NLCD <- terra::project(NLCD, crs(BB))

terra::crop(NLCD, BB, mask = TRUE)
#> class       : SpatRaster 
#> dimensions  : 942, 2199, 1  (nrow, ncol, nlyr)
#> resolution  : 0.0003182295, 0.0003182295  (x, y)
#> extent      : -77.19994, -76.50015, 42.20009, 42.49986  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
#> coord. ref. : lon/lat WGS 84 (EPSG:4326) 
#> source      : memory 
#> color table : 1 
#> categories  : NLCD Land Cover Class, Histogram, Red, Green, Blue, Opacity 
#> name        : example_NLCD_Land_Cover_2019 
#> min value   :                   Open Water 
#> max value   : Emergent Herbaceous Wetlands
```

Comment: Great, thank you. That seems to have worked!